# An error occurred while trying to connect to a web service

Tags: infopath

I created a form in InfoPath which is having a people picker control which need to populate the login user name. To create that created a data connection which talks to `userprofileservice.asmx` web service. Working fine in InfoPath preview when I published it in Server and tried to access from browser getting below error,

> An error occurred querying a data source.  
> Click OK to resume filling
>   out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors.

Hide error details 
An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 
Log ID:5566

Correlation ID:6b10883d-cc49-4fc1-8ba2-c13dc1fa154d

---

An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 
Log ID:5566

Correlation ID:6b10883d-cc49-4fc1-8ba2-c13dc1fa154d

Anybody please help to resolve this?

Comment: Use SharePoint ULS Log Viewer (many available online) and use the Correlation ID to get the exact details of the error.

Comment: No clear message in Log to understand this issue. Anyone already faced this issue? I am very new to SharePoint.

Comment: `The following query failed: GetUserProfileByName (User: 0#.w|domain\c3581, Form Name: Template, IP: , Connection Target: , Request: http://Server/Lists/Registrations/AllItems.aspx, Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:list:-AutoGen-2014-10-20T12:26:58:447Z Type: DataAdapterException, Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.)` Any idea about this comment in log file?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized means the user trying to access doesn't have rights/permissions to access..

Comment: Hi jithu did u resolved this issue I am facing the same issue can you please post solution if you have figured out it. Thanks.